# Cron breaks after upgrading PHP

Tags: php, cron

I'm running CiviCRM 4.5.5, Having recently upgraded to WordPress 4.9.5 and PHP 5.6 (mailing was flawless just prior to this). Latest scheduled mailing failed to initiate, and a URL method test of cron.php generated the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'clone' (T_CLONE), expecting '(' in /.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(207) : eval()'d code on line 1

Is there any simple way to fix this? (After the time it took to set CiviCRM up several years ago, I'm reluctant to upgrade--I'm a volunteer, not a tech.)

Answer (score 4):

As PHP develops, some code that used to work in older versions fails in newer versions.  The CiviCRM code gets updated to accommodate those changes - but obviously if you don't upgrade you don't get those fixes.

Your fix is to downgrade the version of PHP, then upgrade CiviCRM, then upgrade PHP again.  You can find a table of supported PHP vs CiviCRM versions in the [Administration Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-version)

If you need help upgrading see [Find an Expert](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors)  (including me!)

Answer (score 2):

Chris (OP) here. I opted to go with a fresh site, latest version install (PHP 7.1, WP 7.9.6, CiviCRM 5.1.2). Cron still not functioning, so I decided to go with Easycron rather than waste more days of my life. Thanks for your input though guys :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a library included in CiviCRM doesn't work with your new PHP version.

I expect you may be able to successfully upgrade Civi without first downgrading PHP, so try that. If you get errors, then follow @Aidan's advice and downgrade PHP, upgrade CiviCRM, then upgrade PHP again.

Note that you can often install a second version of PHP on the same system and switch between them.